# Sorry ubuntu 13.04 has encountered an internal error

Tags: 13.04

I have been getting error reports at the start  after booting. Sometimes its the same error that pop ups again. Sometimes  its a different one.

[image]

Is this because of some missing package or some service terminated by the OS during boot?.

Can this be resolved? This occurs after updating from 12.10 to 13.04.

Comment: @radu this is not a duplicate this is a different error than the previous one. This looks like applet error. the previous one is different. However the title seems to be the same. Definitely a different error

Comment: @Raghunandan The thing is, even though it is a different error, the idea is the same. *An error occurred.* You can either report and hope for a fix from the developer sooner rather than later. (Or if you are a developer and know what the fix is, you can contribute it yourself. :) ) Or just ignore it altogether (I wouldn't ignore it though)

Comment: @dan ok. i will report the error

Comment: @dan how do i get the package name of the error popped cause i need the same to report bugs in launchapd. Any idea??

Comment: i got it the package name is in the snap shot

Comment: @Raghunandan Btw just clicking `continue`, would report the error, no need to do it manually